# Default DocumentRoot directory redirects to a VirtualHost in Virtualmin

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, documentroot, virtualization

When I try to access DocumentRoot it redirects to one of my VirtualHosts, I can't see contents in /var/www/html.

It's under Virtualmin 3.94 and I think someone else my problem [here](http://www.virtualmin.com/node/18996), but I can't find the options he tried to fix.

How can I fix this please?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're expecting to see, what you're seeing instead, and how your system is configured?  Which `DocumentRoot` are you accessing, and how are you doing it?  If you mean you're trying to access the main server config's `DocumentRoot` and you have `<VirtualHost>`s configured, then their `DocumentRoot`s override that of the main config.

Comment: Thanks, I expect to see Apache Default Page, but I see one of my VirtualHosts instead. my `DocumentRoot` is set to `/var/www/html` and I'm accessing it through browser by typing my server's IP. (also edited my question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have virtual hosts configured on a port, one of them will ***always*** serve a request for that port - the main server isn't used anymore, a request that doesn't match the `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` of a `<VirtualHost>` will get sent to the first `<VirtualHost>` on the port.  The only way the `DocumentRoot` that you've defined globally will be used at all is if the `<VirtualHost>` that handles a request doesn't define its own `DocumentRoot`.

From the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html):

> Main host goes away
>
> If you are adding virtual hosts to an existing web server, you must also create a `<VirtualHost>` block for the existing host. The `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot` included in this virtual host should be the same as the global `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot`. List this virtual host first in the configuration file so that it will act as the default host.

Set yourself up a `<VirtualHost>` to handle the requests that you're trying to send to the main server's `DocumentRoot` - if you're accessing it by IP, just set the vhost to have a `ServerName` of that IP address.